# get all users from table who dont have a row filled out

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

specificaly a user meta table from wordpress. Im trying to get all users who dont have a certain metakey

so for example

user_id   - 1  2  3 3  4 2 1

meta_key  - a  a a b a c c b

met_value - etc

So say with that example i want to get all users who dont have a entry in the database with the meta key of b. which would exclude 3 and 1... the sql query should only return users 2 and 4. i know how to do this easily the other way around, finding all users who have a meta key of B, but i dont know how to write a query that gets every other user who doesnt.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share how you find "all users who have a meta key of B"?

Comment: SELECT * FROM users_meta WHERE meta_key = 'b'

Answer (score 0):

One method is`not eixsts`:

```
select u.*
from users u
where not exists (select 1
                  from metatable m
                  where meta_key = 'b' and m.user_id = u.user_id
                 );
```

If you don't have a separate users table:

```
select distinct m.user_id
from metatable m
where not exists (select 1
                  from metatable m2
                  where m2.meta_key = 'b' and m2.user_id = m.user_id
                 );
```

I would assume the meta table in question is `wp_usermeta`.

Comment: I'd add one adjustment, and alter the ```select``` portion of the query to read ```select distinct u.user_id``` so that we don't end up with duplicates.

Comment: yup, its the wp_usermeta table, its not working for me tho, heres my final sql select u.* from wp_users u where not exists (select 1 from wp_usermeta m where meta_key = '_sfwd-course_progress' and m.user_id = u.ID );

Comment: @blank473 . . . The query in your comment looks correct.  How does it not work?

Comment: dunno, i even tried this one SELECT * FROM wp_users u
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM  wp_usermeta m
        WHERE m.meta_key = '_sfwd-course_progress' and m.user_id = u.ID
    ).... but no luck

Comment: am i doing this part right? $rs=mysql_query($sql);
 
 while($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)){
  echo $data['email']."<br/>"; 
 
 }

Answer (score 0):

```
$users_with_meta = get_users([
    'meta_key' => 'some_key',
    'fields' => ['ID'],
]);

$users_with_meta = [];

foreach($users_with_meta as $user)
    $users_with_meta[] = $user->ID;

$users_without_meta = get_users(['exclude' => $users_with_meta]);
```